# Elasticsearch date format mapping

Tags: php, elasticsearch

So, i have the following date format which i want to import in elasticsearch as a date field :

```
2015-01-12T03:00:00
```

Unfortunately, this format is not recognised by elasticsearch with the following mapping :

```
{
    "mappings": {
      "veenendaal_type_new": {
        "properties": {
          "1061_Mundo_Sport_Veenendaal": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "1076_We_Veenendaal_Bernard_van_Kreelpoort": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "1103_V&D_Veenendaal": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "1167_Action_Veenendaal": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "1171_Speksnijder_Veenendaal": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "1178_Ingang_Corridor_t_h_v__C&A_Veenendaal": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "1181_Ingang_Corridor_t_h_v__Bart_Smit_Veenendaal": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "1183_De_Heren_van_XVII_Veenendaal": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "1184_Corridor_t_h_v__CandyShop_Veenendaal": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "1186_Corridor_t_h_v__Het_Goudhaantje_Veenendaal": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "1188_Takko_Veenendaal": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "1212_De_Cultuurfabriek_Veenendaal": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "1216_Jac_Hensen_Veenendaal": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "1505_Floral_Haircare_Veenendaal": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "201_WE_Veenendaal": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "940_HEMA_Veenendaal": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "Tijdsperiode": {
            "type": "date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Elasticsearch returns this error :

```
MapperParsingException[failed to parse [Tijdsperiode]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: "2015-01-12T03:00:00" is malformed at "T03:00:00"];
```

My question is, how can i make this format **(2015-01-12T03:00:00)** valid for elasticsearch?

Comment: There's a dangling comma in the mapping for the `Tijdsperiode` field, which makes it invalid JSON. How did you install this mapping? can you run `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php, like this:

```
date("c", $date_string);//ISO 8601 2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this in your index definition :

`"Tijdsperiode": {
    "type": "date",
     "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
  }`

or maybe

`"format": "date_time_no_millis"`

http://www.elasticsearch.com/docs/elasticsearch/mapping/date_format/

Comment: `index:not_analyzed` is only for string types, not needed for date types.

Comment: so I change the answer 

`"Tijdsperiode": {
 "type": "date",
  "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
  }`

Answer (score 0):

For dates like `2022-06-14 19:29:06 +00:00` this worked for me in the "format":

`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ`

Reference here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html